# Using lmer for my data?

Tags: lme4-nlme

I´ve been using two-way repeated measurement anova for some time, but recently I started learning about linear mixed effect models. So I´m definitely a novice!

Here´s my project outline (see the data table below):
15 Patients and 15 matched controls received 4 different meals on 4 consecutive days (random order). Meals differed i terms of fat content (none, low, medium, high). The "endpoint" was hormone response (calculated as AUC) measured during the meal ingestion

These are my basic questions:

1) Does the response increase with increasing fat content in the meal?

and,

2) Are **between-group** responses different ("none" vs. "none", "low" vs. "low" etc.)

The model below is very basic, and I can´t figure out if this is the way to do it. How can I dissect the "meal effect" within groups from differences between groups?

---

```
full <- lme(AUC ~ grp + meal, random = ~ 1|subj, data = mixed2)

summary(full)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: mixed2 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  1681.742 1700.956 -833.8708

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | subj
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    300.5491 251.1654

Fixed effects: AUC ~ grp + meal 
                Value Std.Error DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept) 1161.8184  93.00798 87  12.491599  0.0000
grpt2d       282.3685 118.94018 28   2.374038  0.0247
meallow     -635.9783  64.85062 87  -9.806819  0.0000
mealmedium  -581.3927  64.85062 87  -8.965105  0.0000
mealogtt    -839.3693  64.85062 87 -12.943119  0.0000
 Correlation: 
           (Intr) grpt2d meallw melmdm
grpt2d     -0.639                     
meallow    -0.349  0.000              
mealmedium -0.349  0.000  0.500       
mealogtt   -0.349  0.000  0.500  0.500

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-2.3605374 -0.4955454 -0.1377922  0.4907946  3.0098499 

Number of Observations: 120
Number of Groups: 30




> mixed2
    subj grp   meal     AUC
1     S1 con   ogtt  496.00
2     S2 con   ogtt  494.00
3     S3 con   ogtt  234.00
4     S4 con   ogtt  393.00
5     S5 con   ogtt  395.00
6     S6 con   ogtt  259.00
7     S7 con   ogtt  166.00
8     S8 con   ogtt  447.00
9     S9 con   ogtt  289.00
10   S10 con   ogtt  300.00
11   S11 con   ogtt  452.00
12   S12 con   ogtt  147.00
13   S13 con   ogtt  219.00
14   S14 con   ogtt  202.00
15   S15 con   ogtt  192.00
16    S1 con    low  911.00
17    S2 con    low  432.00
18    S3 con    low  464.00
19    S4 con    low  502.00
20    S5 con    low  356.00
21    S6 con    low  445.00
22    S7 con    low  522.00
23    S8 con    low  372.00
24    S9 con    low  563.00
25   S10 con    low  435.00
26   S11 con    low  790.00
27   S12 con    low  355.00
28   S13 con    low  571.00
29   S14 con    low  451.00
30   S15 con    low  434.00
31    S1 con medium  963.00
32    S2 con medium  473.00
33    S3 con medium  385.00
34    S4 con medium  782.00
35    S5 con medium  848.00
36    S6 con medium  340.00
37    S7 con medium  715.00
38    S8 con medium  297.00
39    S9 con medium  720.00
40   S10 con medium  665.00
41   S11 con medium  830.00
42   S12 con medium  149.00
43   S13 con medium  523.00
44   S14 con medium  930.00
45   S15 con medium  367.00
46    S1 con   high 1279.00
47    S2 con   high 1245.00
48    S3 con   high  746.00
49    S4 con   high 1190.00
50    S5 con   high 1334.00
51    S6 con   high 1368.00
52    S7 con   high 1471.00
53    S8 con   high 1098.00
54    S9 con   high 1475.00
55   S10 con   high  681.00
56   S11 con   high 1642.00
57   S12 con   high  568.00
58   S13 con   high  743.00
59   S14 con   high 1228.00
60   S15 con   high 1515.00
61    P1 t2d   ogtt  665.90
62    P2 t2d   ogtt  453.30
63    P3 t2d   ogtt  161.90
64    P4 t2d   ogtt  237.10
65    P5 t2d   ogtt  232.30
66    P6 t2d   ogtt  947.50
67    P7 t2d   ogtt  638.00
68    P8 t2d   ogtt  605.80
69    P9 t2d   ogtt  705.30
70   P10 t2d   ogtt  270.00
71   P11 t2d   ogtt  641.30
72   P12 t2d   ogtt 2321.30
73   P13 t2d   ogtt  157.50
74   P14 t2d   ogtt  518.50
75   P15 t2d   ogtt  668.30
76    P1 t2d    low  769.10
77    P2 t2d    low 1181.30
78    P3 t2d    low  395.73
79    P4 t2d    low  564.30
80    P5 t2d    low  570.00
81    P6 t2d    low  570.00
82    P7 t2d    low  720.80
83    P8 t2d    low  781.80
84    P9 t2d    low  982.30
85   P10 t2d    low  329.30
86   P11 t2d    low 1531.00
87   P12 t2d    low 1764.50
88   P13 t2d    low  343.30
89   P14 t2d    low 1017.30
90   P15 t2d    low  887.00
91    P1 t2d medium  958.30
92    P2 t2d medium  740.80
93    P3 t2d medium  383.10
94    P4 t2d medium  971.90
95    P5 t2d medium  505.50
96    P6 t2d medium  505.50
97    P7 t2d medium 1005.00
98    P8 t2d medium 1275.80
99    P9 t2d medium  900.50
100  P10 t2d medium  685.00
101  P11 t2d medium  942.30
102  P12 t2d medium 1523.00
103  P13 t2d medium  320.80
104  P14 t2d medium  990.80
105  P15 t2d medium  953.00
106   P1 t2d   high 1539.30
107   P2 t2d   high 1915.50
108   P3 t2d   high  831.38
109   P4 t2d   high 1194.50
110   P5 t2d   high 1588.80
111   P6 t2d   high 1074.50
112   P7 t2d   high 1241.30
113   P8 t2d   high 1435.30
114   P9 t2d   high 2489.00
115  P10 t2d   high  743.00
116  P11 t2d   high 1560.80
117  P12 t2d   high 3197.80
118  P13 t2d   high  965.30
119  P14 t2d   high  758.80
120  P15 t2d   high  971.80
```

Comment: What is the order of your `meal`variable? I guess `low < medium < high` but where is `ogtt `? And what does it mean? Is it `none`? Can you make the variable `meal` continous (by looking at the number of calories or percentage of fat in the meals)? Did you tried to interact `grp` and `meal` (by writing `grp * meal`)?

Comment: Since you are already familiar with repeated measure ANOVA, you can simply plug your lme object into the Anova function of the car package, and then you can use the multcomp or phia packages for post-hoc and simple effects testing, respectively. The mixed effect model is just a different way of dealing with the correlated response problem of repeated measures, but can be analysed in the standard ANOVA framework.